# adding hogan support to express

Tags: node.js, express, hogan.js

I want to add hogan support to my express. I have seen [this tutorial](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html) is showing

```
$ express -h

  Usage: express [options] [dir]

  Options:

    -h, --help          output usage information
    -V, --version       output the version number
    -e, --ejs           add ejs engine support (defaults to jade)
        --hbs           add handlebars engine support
    -H, --hogan         add hogan.js engine support
    -c, --css <engine>  add stylesheet <engine> support (less|stylus|compass|sass) (defaults to plain css)
        --git           add .gitignore
    -f, --force         force on non-empty directory
```

but when I am installing in my machine it is showing

```
$ express -h

  Usage: express [options] [path]

  Options:
    -s, --sessions           add session support
    -t, --template <engine>  add template <engine> support (jade|ejs). default=jade
    -c, --css <engine>       add stylesheet <engine> support (stylus). default=plain css
    -v, --version            output framework version
    -h, --help               output help information
```

what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial shows what will be the result if you are running `express -h` with the CLI installed by `npm install -g express-generator`.

Your results are the result of running `express -h` with the CLI included in old versions of express like 2.5.11. The current version 4.3.13 does not have the CLI.

If you are on a Unix-like operating system, you can do `which express` to find out where the file is that you are executing. If it is a system file (e.g., `/usr/local/bin/express`) you can try `npm uninstall -g express && npm install -g express-generator`. Generally, you don't want or need `express` installed globally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to install express 4.3.13 in ubuntu 14.04? when  install it using apt-get install node-express it is installing 2.5.9-2.

Comment: You need to install it via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). As told before, run that command: `npm install -g express-generator`. This will replace the old express binary with a new generator. 

Off the records, they're [planning](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/issues/77) to drop Hogan support with the next major release.

Comment: @GökayGürcan, yes I have installed it by npm but while i run the command express -h on terminal it says "bash: /usr/bin/express: No such file or directory".

Comment: Can you run `npm ls --global --depth=0` and put the output here? Let's see what's in there and what's not.